# How do I make virtual button in Unity using ARToolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

So I was googling about how do I make virtual button in Unity using ARToolkit but I didn't find any source for making that. Though I found that in vuforia we can implement virtual button interface. Anyone can help me how to do this in artoolkit ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could use another marker placed close to your marker and control your script using Events like OnMarkerFound, OnMarkerLost and OnMarkerTracked.